# finding the orthogonal trajectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the orthogonal trajectories of the following function: $x^2+y^2=c$

So first I derive to find the slope of the function:

$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$

The orthogonal slope is the negative reciprocal:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$

Now we need to solve this ODE:

$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$

$ln(x)=ln(y)+c$

$x=y+k$

So the orthogonal trajectories are $y=x-k$?

Comment: it is indeed $y=Cx$ because $\ln(x)=\ln(y)+c =\ln(Cy)$ and it makes sense because radius is orthogonal to boundary of circle.

Comment: $ln(x)=ln(y)+c$ becomes $e^{ln(x)}=e^{ln(y)+c}$,  This equals $x=y*e^c$.  Let $e^c=k$ and you get $x=ky$, NOT $x=y+k$.  In the expression $x=ky$, let $1/k=C$ and you get what K.K. McDonald indicated, $y=Cx$.